# Write and schedule a job on Unix server which is triggered even after the server restart

Tags: python, unix, cron, jobs

I'm trying to create a task on Unix similar to a task of Task Scheduler in Windows which will run at specific times of the day and even gets triggered after server restarts. Aim of this job is to execute a python file.
My question is two parts:

1). How to write a job which I can schedule at multiple times of the day. I tried to write cron job using `crontab` command but it gives `You <user> are not allowed to access to (crontab) because of pam configuration.` I would like to know a way where I can schedule the triggering of python script without needing root/admin rights.

2). How can I schedule a job whose scheduling stays in effect even after the server is restarted. While going through various resources, I found `systemd`, using which we can use to start and stop the services. For example, [https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-write-a-simple-systemd-service#:~:text=%20How%20To%20Write%20A%20Simple%20Systemd%20Service,section%20that%20you%20need%20to%20w...%20More%20](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-write-a-simple-systemd-service#:%7E:text=%20How%20To%20Write%20A%20Simple%20Systemd%20Service,section%20that%20you%20need%20to%20w...%20More%20)
.But I'm unable to find how i can write a service script which will run my python script.

Can someone please guide on how can I run a job which executes my python script a some specific times of day and keeps working even after server bounce.

Answer (score 0):

First PAM error say you do not have permissions so check `/etc/security/access.conf` and add line

```
+ : youruser : cron crond :0 tty1 tty2 tty3 tty4 tty5 tty6
```

For exec cron job on boot add in cron line like this:

```
@reboot  /path/to/your_program
```

Comment: I can't update the configuration file of the server. That's the issue in going with this approach and so I'm seeking an alternative.

Comment: @Akanksha_p, what about to run a `cron` with user who have rights to do it?

Comment: Yes, i have to run the job at some specific time of day, i think ```crontab``` could help. But since it's needing admin rights, I'm asking if some other alternative is there which can achieve the same.

Comment: @Akanksha_p, contact your administrator and ask to give you rights to use cron.